# connect one Output to two diffrent Inputs of two components in Modelica?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I want to connect one single OUTPUT of an evaporator to two different INPUTS of two valves (as shown in the code main_1), and also trying to see if its possible to connect two OUTPUTS of two valves to a single INPUT of an evaporator (as shown in code main_2) in MODELICA, is that possible?
-model evaporator have one input and one output.
-model evaporator_2 have one input and one output.

```
    model main_1
evaporator EVAP;
valve_a valve_1;
valve_b valve_2;
equation
connect(EVAP.port_out,valve_1.port_in);
connect(EVAP.port_out,valve_2.port_in);
end main_1

    model main_2
evaporator_2 EVAP;
valve_c valve_3;
valve_d valve_4;
equation
connect(valve_3.port_out,EVAP.port_in,);
connect(valve_4.port_out,EVAP.port_in);
end main_2
```

Comment: Plugging one output into multiple inputs should work fine, but what do you expect when you put two outputs on one input? Should they be added up or something similar? For that matter you can use the desired block from `Modelica.Blocks` and combine those outputs.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, for the 2nd case to put two outputs on one input ,i desire to be added,but in my model the tow outputs are outputs of tow valves they dont open in the same time ,when the 1st valve is open the 2nd valve is set to be closed,i dont have a case whe the two valves are opend in the same time,but i think i desire theme to be added if i have both valves opened

Comment: and i have a question ,if there is an example in modelica where they use Modelica.Blocks.Routing.Multiplex2 ? so that i know how to use it, and thanks again

Comment: This model uses the multiplex block: `Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Components.AngleToTorqueAdaptor`.

Comment: thanks it was helpful your comment

Comment: with multiplex i can just sum tow signals ,because in my case i need to connect Prerssure ,Enthalpy,masse flow rate and energy ,so if i use multiplex i dont use a thermofluide connector?

Comment: i mean i have tow input ports which are a thermofluid connector ports

Comment: I don't know if i follow correctly, but in general there is a big difference between `input`/`output` and `connector`.  For `input`/`output` the flow of information (with small exceptions) is predefined. Using `connector` does not really constrain that, but you have to define a `flow` and a `potential` variable. You can connect as many connectors as you want. For any node connecting multiple connectors all potentials are set equal and the sum of the flow variables equals zero. In that case you don't need to combine the connectors with blocks.

Comment: ah oky i get it thanks,it was my fault to say input instade of saying a port of connector

Comment: Well from your example i should have seen that you meant connects. :)